# On the main page the delete icon for the 'Interesting Tags' should be vertically aligned

Tags: feature-request

I believe these images (the small 'x') should be vertically aligned to the box that shows the name of the tag and will look slightly better. They look nice but a little bit 'slapped on' at this stage.

Apart from that the site is great !